# Express render() doesn't work in post request

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to do a redirect in a post request, but it doesn't work for me.
Here is the express.js code that should do it:

```
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use("/",express.static('public'));

app.post("/sendMovieData", async(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body)
  res.render("../view/movie-selected")
})
```

And also here is the fetch request.

```
    let requestBody = {
        "movieName": movie.getAttribute("data-movieName"),
        "image": e.target.src,
        "city": JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("city_country")).city,
        "country": JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("city_country")).country
    }
    fetch('/sendMovieData', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    });
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the response in your client side javascript.

Comment: Wdym? I am sending the request on my js side, and on my server side i receive it and redirect to another page

Comment: You're using `fetch` to send this request. Your browser isn't going to do anything with that response. You have to do something with it from your javascript code.

Comment: can you give me an example what should i do.

Comment: all the stuff must happen on the server side